# Maxed Out Energy / Ecology values

Tags: prosperity

What happens when a player reaches one beyond the maximum possible value on their individual board's economy or ecology tracks ?

[image]

Do energy and ecology values start being tallied beyond 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1123224/energyecology-level-beyondbelow-limit) on BGG suggests a co-designer has clarified that -7/+7 is not a hard limit.  I couldn't find the exact post to clarify that but one of the designers has been very active answering questions.

Something in the rules [here](http://www.ystari.com/prosperity/ProsperityUS.pdf) say is.

> Note: at any time, the players can recalculate their energy and
>   ecology totals to check that they haven’t made a mistake

This to me would imply that you can move beyond -7/+7 as it can be recalculated at any time.  If you stopped moving at the extremes then its possible that the total couldn't be calculated in retrospect.